# .NET Core - EntityFrameworkCore - Unable to cast object of type 'Query.Internal.EntityQueryable` to type 'DbSet`

Tags: asp.net-core, entity

I try to implement a search with entity when a search field is provided

but I get a weird casting error I just dont understand

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[SomeApp.Models.Partner]' to type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet`1[SomeApp.Models.Partner]'.
```

here is the code of my controller entry point

I tried forcing the cast, but apparently there is something wrong with my code

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<PartnersFetch>> GetPartners(PartnersSearch partnersSearch)
{
    DbSet<Partner> data = _context.Partners;
    if (partnersSearch.SearchById != null)
    {
        // the following line causes problems :
        data = (DbSet <Partner>) data.Where( p => p.Id == partnersSearch.SearchById.GetValueOrDefault());
    }
```

thanks for helping me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to use AsQueryable

```
var data = _context.Partners.AsQueryable();
if (partnersSearch.SearchById != null)
{
    data = data.Where( p => p.Id == partnersSearch.SearchById.GetValueOrDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.Where(...)` will return an IQueryable which you can materialize as follows

`List<Partner> myResult = data.Where(...).ToList();`

The `DbSet<Partner>` is only the set on which you can query data. Your goal very likely is to get the partners out of it, right?

Comment: the goal is to add where queries for each search fiel provided by the post request